# With bash on Windows 10, why does it execute my $() as separate commands?

Tags: mysql, windows, git-bash, minikube

I'm learning how to work with Docker and Minikube on a Windows 10 Home computer.  I've installed the needed software OK.  I've installed Docker, minikube, kubectl, and a recent version of MySQL, properly pathed so its CLI can be used.  I'm using either the Bash console provided by GIT, and/or the Bash console provided by Cygwin.  Both seem to provide the same (bad) results.

I start Docker, and install the MySQL service.  The kubectl get all shows everything running OK.

Per the programming book I'm working through, I want to try accessing MySQL through this command:

```
mysql -h $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.IP}}") -P $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.Port}}") -u root -p
```

The result should be the MySQL CLI prompt, like mysql>  .  Instead I get this behavior:

1. A popup window stating "Windows cannot find '192.168.99.101'.  Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."
2. The console text:

   The system cannot find the file 192.168.99.101.

   *

   X open url failed: 192.168.99.101: exit status 1

   *

   * minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:

   - (URL for sending an error message)
3. A popup window stating "Windows cannot find '31067'.  Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."
4. The console text:

   mysql: [ERROR] Unknown suffix '|' used for variable 'port' (value (gives the border fence that surrounds the output from  minikube service mysql-svc  .)
   mysql: [ERROR] (path to mysql.exe): Error while setting value '|-----|--- (etc)' to 'port'

The expected behavior is to insert an IP and Port into the mysql command line, then firing a command like  mysql -h http://192.168.99.101 -P 31067 -u root -p  .

I think that the problem is with the using the Bash console in a Windows environment.  Any explanation is appreciated.

Thanks,

Jerome.

**UPDATE ON 8/7/2020:**

I'm asked to more thoroughly document my issue.  Here we go.

Here is what Docker knows:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                        TAG
      IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
logicaltiger/cloudnative-statelessness-posts                      latest
      3a3c66daf7f3        5 days ago          139MB
logicaltiger/cloudnative-statelessness-connections                latest
      d060e9857f49        5 days ago          139MB
logicaltiger/cloudnative-statelessness-connectionposts-stateful   latest
      ce33f0966380        5 days ago          123MB
openjdk                                                           8-jdk-alpine
      a3562aa0b991        15 months ago       105MB
mysql                                                             8.0.12
      ee1e8adfcefb        22 months ago       484MB
```

Here is my reconfiguring of minikube.  Other posters suggested that minikube runs iffy unless given a lot of resources.

```
$ minikube delete
* Deleting "minikube" in virtualbox ...
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.

$ minikube start --cpus=4 --memory=4096
* minikube v1.12.1 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Automatically selected the virtualbox driver
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=4, Memory=4096MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=192.168.99.100
  - no_proxy=192.168.99.100
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.18.3 on Docker 19.03.12 ...
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.99.100
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
* Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

After starting mysql from its yaml file I have it running:

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mysql-7dbfd4dbc4-b2tmm   1/1     Running   0          2m55s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          A
GE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          6
m43s
service/mysql-svc    NodePort    10.102.7.119   <none>        3306:32235/TCP   2
m55s

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mysql   1/1     1            1           2m55s

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mysql-7dbfd4dbc4   1         1         1       2m55s
```

Now get the mysql-svc URL:

```
$ minikube service mysql-svc --url
http://192.168.99.102:32235
```

Try to run the book example.  Again I get the two popup windows and what is shown below in the terminal.  I omit the popup window text here...

```
$ mysql -h $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.IP}}") -P $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.Port}}") -u root -p
The system cannot find the file 192.168.99.102.
*
X open url failed: 192.168.99.102: exit status 1
*
* minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open
an issue:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
The system cannot find the file 32235.
*
X open url failed: 32235: exit status 1
*
* minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open
an issue:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
mysql: [ERROR] Unknown suffix '|' used for variable 'port' (value '|-----------|
-----------|-------------|-------|')
mysql: [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe: Error whil
e setting value '|-----------|-----------|-------------|-------|' to 'port'
```

I'm asked what happens if I put in the IP directly.  From above, that IP was http://192.168.99.102:32235

```
$ mysql -h http://192.168.99.102 -P 32235 -u root -p
Enter password: **********
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'http://192.168.99.102' (0)
```

When directly entering the IP and Port, the MySQL server *IS* reached (see the "Enter password:" prompt) but the request is refused.  I'm thinking that I don't know how to make MySQL use the HTTP request.

But is the MySQL not knowing what to do with the IP, and the way that the indirect method (minikube service mysql -svc ...), related?

Continuing, I edit my cookbook-deployment-posts.yaml file with the MySQL address:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: posts-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts
  labels:
    app: posts
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: posts
        image: cdavisafc/cloudnative-statelessness-posts
        env:
          - name: INSTANCE_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
          - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
            value: '{"spring":{"datasource":{"url":"jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.102:32235/cookbook"}}}'
```

Going to kubectl get all, the posts-svc continually starts, errors out and reboots.  Don't know what is wrong...

Jerome.

Comment: Does this `then firing a command like mysql -h http://192.168.99.101 -P 31067 -u root -p` actually work? `I start Docker, and install the MySQL service.` You mean you deployed a mysql pod and service? docker is docker, kubernetes is kubernetes.  Take a look at example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/). Could you add output from `kubectl get all`?

Answer (score 1):

I now see a number of things going wrong.

**First**, I keep thinking that the mysql call is somehow related to the MySQL installed on my PC.  It never is.  Just because I manually create a cookbook database on my PC instance doesn't mean that the textbook example thru Docker / Minikube ever references it.

**Second**, the textbook is missing the --url from its minikube requests.  Here is what is happening.

```
> kubectl create -f mysql-deployment.yaml

> minikube service mysql-svc --url
http://192.168.99.102:31030

> minikube service mysql-svc
```

This opens the web browser to show the service at 192.168.99.102:31030.  *The mysql service doesn't render a web page, but that doesn't matter to this example.*  The console then shows the details of the service (namespace, name, target port, url) in an ASCII box.

```
minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.IP}}"
```

This wants to open the web browser to show the service at http://192.168.99.102, with an implied port of 80.  But there is nothing there, and Windows complains at a popup box.  The console then complains about not opening that url.

```
minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.Port}}"
```

This wants to open the web browser to show the service at 31030, which isn't a valid URL.  Complaints, complaints.

What I really wanted all along is to add the --url to the minikube bits:

```
mysql -h $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.IP}}" --url) -P $(minikube service mysql-svc --format "{{.Port}}" --url) -u root -p
```

This connects to the managed mysql in the console, yielding the mysql> prompt.  Now I can run 'create database cookbook;'.

Solved!